# Typename already in use: Json2Apex

Tags: apex

> Type name already in use: Json2Apex

When I try the simple code in the Dev Console, I get the above error.

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {
    public static void consumeObject(JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }

    public class JSON2Apex {
        public List<String> animals {get;set;} 

        public JSON2Apex(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'animals') {
                            animals = new List<String>();
                            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                                animals.add(new String(parser));
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'JSON2Apex consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return new JSON2Apex(System.JSON.createParser(json));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have an inner class and outer class with the same name.

```
public class CannotDoThis
{
    public class CannotDoThis { /*implementation*/ }
}
```

You can just rename the inner class, or move the properties up a level. You don't really need an inner class here, nor any custom parser for that matter.

```
public class MyRenamedClass
{
    public List<String> animals;

    // additional implementation if you feel you need it

    public static MyRenamedClass parse(String payload)
    {
        return (MyRenamedClass)JSON.deserialize(payload, MyRenamedClass.class);
    }
}
```